# запуск приложения по времени на android

Tags: android

есть приложение по работе с графикой и как сделать его запуск в определенное время?

Comment: На вопрос дан конкретный ответ. По внешним проявлениям похоже, что вопрос можно тоже считать конкретным. Аналогичный вопрос на большом СО имеет хорошую оценку.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен AlarmManager для установки "будильника" и BroadcastReceiver который словит событие о том что время настало.

Пример:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454059/1159507
Переводить смыла не вижу, т.к. там один код.